# Javascript wildcard variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, wildcard

The value of `product_id` might be some combination of letters and numbers, like: GB47NTQQ.

I want to check to see if all but the 3rd and 4th characters are the same.

Something like:

```
if product_id = GBxxNTQQ //where x could be any number or letter.
    //do things
else
    //do other things
```

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regular expression and string.match(). Periods are single wildcard characters.

```
string.match(/GB..NTQQ/);
```

Comment: This post is old, but I'd just suggest using `/GB\w\wNTQQ/`, since OP was looking for letters and numbers. `\w` matches alphanumeric and underscore. To exclude underscore and only use alphanumeric, you could do: `/GB[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}NTQQ/`

Answer (score 5):

Use a [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.info) match:

```
if ('GB47NTQQ'.match(/^GB..NTQQ$/)) {
    // yes, matches
}
```

Comment: Regex in javascript, very nice :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Answers so far have suggested `match`, but `test` is likely more appropriate as it returns *true* or *false*, whereas `match` returns *null* or an array of matches so requires (implicit) type conversion of the result within the condition.

```
if (/GB..NTQQ/.test(product_id)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't *really* make a lot of difference, but yeah, you're right... +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (myString.match(/regex/)) { /*Success!*/ }
```

You can find more information here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html