# Javascript Unscramble and display

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a web page that people can go onto and unscramble a name from a list of names they have entered.

For example,

If the person has the scrambled up name ' *bunn ' (actual name: Bunny). Then they can enter that into box 1.

They the enter a list of names for example: | Bunny | Hetfield | Tither | Roquelaure |

They then click a button which will initiate a program/software/whatever that will take the string ' *bunn ' and match it against the list of name and then display what the scrambled up name actually is.

So it would go something like.

Enter: *bunn

Enter: | Bunny | Hetfield | Tither | Roquelaure |

Click Button

Display to user: Unscrambled name is: Bunny ((- 100% Match)This is optional but would be nice to have maybe later on)

or if no name found,

Display to user: No name found. Possible matches: bunt (- 60% Match) | bann (- 90% Match)

I even made a picture of what I'm talking about.
http://landofducky.webuda.com/random/thing.jpg

It can be done, I've seen it done but It's been impossible for me to get in contact with the person that made it.
Thanks

Comment: Honestly this isn't a suitable question for SO; this is a place to ask specific troubleshooting questions about your code. If you're looking for a place to start, google "javascript word descrambler" and start looking through source code to see what's been done. Here's one example: http://textmechanic.com/Word-Scrambler.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split each of the entered names using the split() method.

```
var name = document.getElementById('theIDwheretheyenteredtheirname').value;

name.split("");
```

This would turn EBN (supposed to be BEN) in to ["E"], ["B"], ["N"] in name[0], name[1], name[2], respectively. Then you would need to split the four options in the same way. Then you would need to write a recursive for loop that checks each letter of the original name against each of the four options letters. If there's a letter match, add a percentage on to a variable that tracks for the best match (i.e. if B is matched against a name like Bob, you're likely going to return a 66% match, since it will match against two B's - of course you can tell your code to stop as soon as it finds a match). At the end simply display the total percentages OR display the name that matched 100%.

There's probably a better way to explain this (or do it even) than I can, but I thought I'd give a shotat answering.

Wildcard matching I believe will involve regex, which you can learn about here:

[Javascript wildcard variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920948/javascript-wildcard-variable)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I'm looking for a place to start and then continue from there. This has been a great help!